# How to resolve: Error Connecting to Substrate [object Event]

Tags: rust, substrate

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/interact

I m trying to interact with blockchain n/w on my local as per given description in above link. But it is showing me following on my browser(http://localhost:8000/substrate-front-end-template):

Error Connecting to Substrate
[object Event]

How to resolve this error as I am new to substrate I dont know..Plz Help

Comment: I'm not sure if the trailing `/substrate-front-end-template` is required in the URL but I'm also not sure if that's the source of your error. Can you open the developer console and see if there are any errors there?

Comment: @DanForbes, thanks for ur help. Actually the problem was substrate node was not running at backend side of my local. So it were unable to generate blocks and connect to network.

Answer (score 4):

The substrate-front-end-template will connect to substrate by `ws://127.0.0.1:9944`, which is to localhost, so you can open the develop tools in chrome to check if it connect success.

Note that if you open the page not in the chain which running, you need to change config in src/config/development.json.

Also to start the node by substrate with `--ws-external`